# Is it possible to wrap a div with 2 additional divs in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="childDivToWrapTwice">Content</div>

var parent = $("<div />");
var child = $("<div />");
child.wrap(parent);
$("#childDivToWrapTwice").wrap(child);
```

This doesn't seem to be working even though you would think it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var parent = $("<div />");
var child = $("<div />");
$("#childDivToWrapTwice").wrap(parent).wrap(child);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6yG6T/)